# How to detect a user changing form data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server"/>
```

C#:

```
public hello(){
    Debug.WriteLines("Current value is: " + tb1.Value);
}
```

I have a timer that will run hello() every 2 seconds on page start. Assuming tb1 has a default value of "Bob", this will be correctly output every 2 seconds. Let's say I type something into tb1 and replace the default value to "Fred". However, "Bob" is *still* output every 2 seconds even though I've replaced the current value.

How do I fix this so that hello() looks into the current value of tb1 instead of what is snapshotted on startup?

---

My ultimate goal is to detect when a user types in information, so I can show/hide form elements on demand depending on what they're currently typing out. If there's an easier way than to constantly check values without having the client do anything other than continue filling out information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onchange attribute and call a function when the text changes rather than checking every 10 seconds and save some resources.

Something like

```
<asp:Textbox id="myTextbox" runat="server" onChange="txtChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Then in the code behind something like

```
public void txtChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get text
    string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    Debug.WriteLines("Current value is: " + text);
}
```

There are several reasons why you should avoid this timer approach to detecting user input.

Effiency: It's inefficient to call the method every 10 seconds no matter what the user is doing.

User Experience: It creates a poor user experience when Bob has to wait an extra ten seconds for the form to update.

Maintainability: It also makes the code less maintainable especially when this timer approach is taken to the extreme because there is a less direct correlation between the interface and the code behind.

Comment: Consider adding explanation why OP's approach with server side timer makes no sense to make this answer complete.

Comment: I added some explanation. Anything else you would add?

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer rlwheeler! 
I'm getting an error when the textbox is changed: "'txtChanged' is undefined"
I'm sure it's a scope issue so I'm putting my function in the wrong area. Where should I be placing that snippet? It's currently in the same scope level as my Page_Load snippet. I've searched through the web for a few hours but I can't find anything understandable